# How to optimize this method for the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would to optimize this method:

```
def get_sentiment_score(text):
    text = text.split()
    positive = 0
    negative = 0
    for word in text:
        if word in positive_words:
            positive += 1
        elif word in negative_words:
            negative += 1
    score = positive - negative
    if score == 0:
        return "UNCERTAIN"
    return "POSITIVE" if score > 0 else "NEGATIVE"

df["sentiment_polarity"] = df["text"].apply(lambda row: get_sentiment_score(str(row)))
```

The variables positive_words and negative_words contains more than 2000 elements in the list each and the dataframe has 270K+ rows.

The total time it takes for me currently is 1000+ seconds.

I would like to bring it down to sub-100 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can convert `positive_words` and `negative_words` from the `list` to `set` to speed up the search.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, it worked! The method now takes only 1.6 seconds to run. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would use `set` and `numpy` with `pandas` split.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


dataf = pd.DataFrame({"text":["hello world is over", "go big or go home"]})

# transform your lists to set
positive_set = {"world", "over"}
negative_set = {"is", "go"}

# use intersection and find length 
def check(s:set) -> int:

    positive = len(s.intersection(positive_set))
    negative = len(s.intersection(negative_set))
    
    return positive - negative
    

# apply it using pandas string slips
dataf["sentiment"] = dataf["text"].str.split().map(set).map(check)

# use numpy to tag
condition = [dataf["sentiment"].gt(0), dataf["sentiment"].lt(0), dataf["sentiment"].eq(0)]

choices = ["POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE", "UNCERTAIN"]

dataf["sentiment"] = np.select(condition, choices)
```

Comment: I am getting ```TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable``` on the ```dataf["text"].str.split().map(set).map(check)```

Comment: This is because you have a `None` values. You can select non-None values and perform the action: `dataf[lambda d: ~d["text"].isna(), "text"].str…`

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, it depends on how big `positive_words` and `negative_words` are in comparison to `text`. I guess they are comparatively small.

You could use a `collections.Counter` over the `text` and sum over all positive / negative words. I guess this is quicker than your for-loop, because I guess `collections.Counter` is implemented more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

From a toy `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id,text
123,hello ok
234,how are you
345,fine and you
456,good what a lovely day
567,it is raining badly"""), sep=',')
>>> df
    id      text
0   123     hello ok
1   234     how are you
2   345     fine and you
3   456     good what a lovely day
4   567     it is raining badly
```

And having settled which words are `positive` and `negative` as suggested in your example :

```py
>>> positive_words = set(['fine', 'good', 'lovely'])
>>> negative_words = set(['raining', 'badly'])
```

We can use the `isin()` method and a `groupby.sum()` to count the number of word we have from the `positive` and `negative` list of words :

```py
>>> df['positive'] = df['text'].str.split().explode().isin(positive_words).groupby(level=0).sum()
>>> df['negative'] = df['text'].str.split().explode().isin(negative_words).groupby(level=0).sum()
>>> df
    id      text                    positive    negative
0   123     hello ok                0           0
1   234     how are you             0           0
2   345     fine and you            1           0
3   456     good what a lovely day  2           0
4   567     it is raining badly     0           2
```

Then, we can make a subtraction by columns `positive` and `negative` to get the `score` :

```py
>>> df['score'] = df['positive'] - df['negative']
>>> df
    id      text                    positive    negative    score
0   123     hello ok                0           0               0
1   234     how are you             0           0               0
2   345     fine and you            1           0               1
3   456     good what a lovely day  2           0               2
4   567     it is raining badly     0           2              -2
```

To finish, we use `loc` to set the `sentiment_polarity` based on the `score` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df.loc[df['score'] > 0, 'sentiment_polarity'] = 'POSITIVE'
>>> df.loc[df['score'] < 0, 'sentiment_polarity'] = 'NEGATIVE' 
>>> df.loc[df['score'] ==0, 'sentiment_polarity'] = 'UNCERTAIN'
>>> df.drop(['positive', 'negative', 'score'], axis=1)
    id      text                    sentiment_polarity
0   123     hello ok                UNCERTAIN
1   234     how are you             UNCERTAIN
2   345     fine and you            POSITIVE
3   456     good what a lovely day  POSITIVE
4   567     it is raining badly     NEGATIVE
```

This should be quite fast to compute compare to the usage of a `lambda` and all of this is fully included in `pandas`, so no need of any additional library.